# still having trouble with my FCM http request

Tags: json, swift, http-headers, firebase-cloud-messaging, nsdictionary

I just want to be able to send a notification to users subscribed to a certain topic with no errors.

Here is my function I use to try to accomplish this goal:

```
 func sendNotificationToUser(to topic: String, title: String, body: String) {
   
    let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectname-41f12/messages:send HTTP/1.1"
    guard let encodedURLString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) else { return }
    let url = URL(string: encodedURLString)!
    
    struct PostBody: Codable {
        struct Message: Codable {
            let topic: String
            let notification: [[String: String]]
        }
        let message: Message
    }
    
    let postBody = PostBody(message: PostBody.Message(topic: topic,
                                                      notification: [
                                                        ["title": title],
                                                        ["body": body]
                                                                                ]))
    
    
   let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? encoder.encode(postBody)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer ya29.\(self.bearer)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let jsonData = data {
                if let jsonDataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDictionary))")
                }
                
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err)
            print(postBody.message)
            
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Here is the function when I call it after a button press:

```
 getTheSchoolID { (id) in
            if let id = id {
                self.sendNotificationToUser(to: id, title: "New Event Added!", body: "A new event has been added to the dashboard!!")

            }
        }
```

When I press the button I kept getting an NSCocoaError and I still do, so I did my research and put my JSON through on [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) and it was validated by simply changing the brackets to curly brackets and adding double quotes around the objects. Now when I run it in Swift, I get errors like so:

[image: errors]

The JSON data is printed in the middle between the errors, I can't see anything wrong with the JSON, is there an issue in my http request?

**Edit** The JSON Structure I want:

[image: json structure]

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid - you are mixing up dictionaries and arrays in a way that doesn't work for most tools.  You need to embed your dicts in {...}.  The following modification (expanded/indented to the max to show structure) works, and as far as I can tell is the same structure:

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "topic": "23452345234"
    },
    {
      "notification": [
        {
          "body": "messsage"
        },
        {
          "title": "new event"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If for some reason you want an array rather than a dict, then embed all the above in square brackets for a single item array.

Howwever I'd probably use a temporary struct to generate the body, and then rely on `Encodable` to do the work for me.  A rough solution is below (there are many things that could be improved - not hard-coding the dict keys, passing in a formed dict, proper handling of errors etc from the encoder, ...) but hopefully this will get you started.

```
func sendNotificationToUser(to topic: String, title: String, body: String) {
   
   struct PostBody: Codable {
      struct Message: Codable {
         let topic: String
         let notification: [String: String]
      }
      let message: Message
   }

   // generate the request...

   let postBody = PostBody(message: PostBody.Message(
                              topic: topic,
                              notification: [
                                 "title": title,
                                 "body": body ]
                              ) 
                             )
   
   let encoder = JSONEncoder()
   encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
   request.httpBody = try? encoder.encode(postBody)

   // finish request, completion handler, etc, etc
}
```

The JSON generated is

```
{
  "message" : {
    "topic" : "topictext",
    "notification" : {
      "title" : "titleText",
      "body" : "bodyText"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so how can I do that in my Swift http function I posted above? Can I use those brackets in the `paramString` variable? I'll add an image of the exact json structure I want. @flanker

Comment: @dsonawave edited answer to give you a bare-bones starting point

Comment: My initial guess at the json structure based on the error message wasn't correct (due to the brackets sprayed around).  My `ctual output is vry similar to your structure, but the notification values are in an array ... as they are an array of dict.

Comment: Yeah I don't know man. I still get the same errors, if it's not "Invalid value around character 0." Then it's "no value". @flanker

Comment: So the structure in the image in the Firebase docs above is the **exact** same structure as the JSON you're showing me right now. Correct? @flanker

Comment: gonna edit the post so you can see my code with your answer. @flanker

Comment: Had a daft mistake in my data struct - the problem with doing it at 3am and not being able to test it.  Editing my answer soon...

Comment: No worries let me know when you're finished editing. @flanker

Comment: Ok just seen that you actually edited it already lol, I tested it out and it still doesn't work for some odd reason.  @flanker

Comment: OK, not sure there's much more I can do to help.  Your sample json decodes on my machine, and I can then reverse it and encode it to get the original json back out.  Sure you have no typos?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229517/discussion-between-flanker-and-dsonawave).